# Disable history and URL state while using React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Any quick-and-easy answer to the scenario where you want to build something like a simple questionnaire with React and React Router where you don't want the user to be able to modify the URL to browse anywhere and you also don't want to push history state into the browser, essentially preventing use of the back button?

Sample routes might look like:

```
questions/1
questions/2
questions/3
...so on
```

But the URL should stay the same at all times and the history won't change, essentially what a single page app without routing would behave like.

Comment: Any solution that worked?

Comment: No solution that involved the use of React Router, unfortunately at the time I was using it, it wasn't possible, so I decided to forego the effort.

Answer (score 2):

For the history part, you would need to use [`replaceWith()`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/api/mixins/Navigation.md#replacewithroutenameorpath-params-query) everywhere you want to change route.

If you're using `<Link>`, you could create your own version which uses `replaceWith` instead of `transitionTo` - you should just be able to [copy its implementation](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/559c60435ce3dbdd5cdad7b5e572544edb46dd9e/modules/components/Link.js) and replace the `PropTypes` require call with `require('react-router/lib/PropTypes')`.

I can't immediately think of a non-horrible way to prevent the user from jumping around though -  presumably you also want the app to break if they try to start on anything but the base URL? I would just use some simple state to control which component is currently being rendered instead of using React Router if that's the behaviour you really want.